# Laravel - Prevent Multiple Login Of Same Credentials

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a Laravel web app where multiple users login but I need to prevent login if the user has already logged.

I know that Laravel has a method (**logoutOtherDevices**) that logout the current user when another user with same credentials be logged.

But I need the following:

I have 2 users with same credentials..

1. User 1 is logged.
2. When User 2 is going to login, the application should not allow login and show a message.

How can I implement something like that?

Comment: that's a bad concept to implement, imagine the same user closed his navigator without logging out, and when he tries to login again (session lost/another browser/ private mode/...) he wont be able to login again. and if he clears the cache and session , he will be locked forever from his account unless you do it with a heartbeat where the browser sends a request `still logged in` every X seconds. wich will lead to your server being spammed.

Comment: "I have 2 users with same credentials.." How can there be 2 users with exactly same credentials - same username/email and same password?

Comment: Hi @N69s, you are right. The other way can be use the laravel method logoutOtherDevices to logout the first user when the second user is login. But this method do not show any message when logout the user. I would like to inform the logged out user that another user has logged in.

Answer (score -3):

When second user tries login .. Check if logout method returns something..Tweak existing function of kharavel logoutother method..
Good luck

Comment: care to elaborate. How you know it's THE second user ? logout function will return nothing since he's not logged in yet. logoutOther do the opposite of what OP wanted.